# reverse order Ember model collection inside component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm pulling model data inside my IndexRoute by using:

http://pastebin.com/pf1mBgTU

And I have a component that's being passed the notifications.

I need to be able to reverse the order of those notifications though.

The problem is that since I'm pulling multiple models into the IndexRoute - I can't use `sortProperties` inside of the IndexController.

Anyone know how to sort these either before they get sent to the component, or from inside the component itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the controller's `Sortable` mixin to do this for you...

```
App.IndexController= Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortFunction(x,y) {
        // here check for model type and make comparison between x and y
    }
});
```

Set your sort property to something that will have your type information, like a `meta` section.  If you don't have such an identifier, you may need to instead implement `orderBy`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Steve! When I try to make an IndexController that extends from Ember.ArrayController, it errors out - 'Error while loading route: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addArrayObserver'.

This is because the IndexRoute isn't returning an array of objects, but rather - an object that holds arrays of objects (it's using Em.RSVP).

Is there another way that I can sort? Perhaps modifying the content on initialize?